# Convert given String to a Date object

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a given String `2019-04-17 10:00:43+02:00` and want to convert it to something like `Mon Apr 15 12:05:47 CEST 2019`

I tried:

---

```
String date = "2019-04-17T11:02:46+02:00"
SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ssX ");
java.util.Date result = formatter.parse(date);
```

but it gives an Exception like below.

> Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
>   "2019-04-17 11:02:46+02:00"
>       at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)

Comment: Use `MM` for months .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Also, spaces in strings matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a default ISO format which can be parsed as is with `OffsetDateTime`:

```
String date = "2019-04-17T11:02:46+02:00";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(date);
```

If you *really* need a `java.util.Date`, you can then use:

```
Date legacyDate = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is you have put a extra space in the formatter.

```
String date = "2019-04-17T11:02:46+02:00";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ssX");
Date rst = format.parse(date);
System.out.println(rst);
```

output :

```
Thu Jan 17 14:32:46 IST 2019
```